# Undefined reference to cv::redirectError while creating shared build of OpenCV 3.1 with Mingw

Tags: windows, opencv, installation, opencv3.0, mingw32

**Programs and versions: Windows 10, Mingw32 with gcc 6.1.0, Cmake 3.6.1, (Code::blocks 16.01)**

First of all, I should mention that building a static build does work perfectly, just building a shared build does not work and I don't find workarounds for my specific problem.

I tried to build OpenCV3.1 with the abovementioned programs as shared build. Using cmake's default settings, I get following error:

```
[ 34%] Linking CXX executable ..\..\bin\opencv_test_core.exe
../../lib/libopencv_ts310.a(ts.cpp.obj):ts.cpp:(.text$_ZN6cvtest2TS4initERKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEE+0x119): undefined reference to `cv::redirectError(int (*)(int, char const*, char const*, char const*, int, void*), void*, void**)'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
modules\core\CMakeFiles\opencv_test_core.dir\build.make:885: recipe for target 'bin/opencv_test_core.exe' failed
mingw32-make[2]: *** [bin/opencv_test_core.exe] Error 1
CMakeFiles\Makefile2:1713: recipe for target 'modules/core/CMakeFiles/opencv_test_core.dir/all' failed
mingw32-make[1]: *** [modules/core/CMakeFiles/opencv_test_core.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:159: recipe for target 'all' failed
mingw32-make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Default settings in my case means (among others): BUILD_TBB = off, BUILD_WITH_DYNAMIC_IPP = off, BUILD_opencv_world = off, ENALBE_OMIT_FRAME_POINTER = on, ENABLE_SSE/SSE2/SSE3 = on, WITH_IPP and WITH_IPP_A = off (as this seems to cause a common problem in some cases when activated).

**The question now is: What does that error mean and how to fix it?**

Obviously some function is missing: `` undefined reference to `cv::redirectError(int (*)(int, char const*, char const*, char const*, int, void*), void*, void**) ``. Searching the source code gives some definitions of this function in

1. `system.cpp`: Line 662: `redirectError( CvErrorCallback errCallback, void* userdata, void** prevUserdata)`
2. `utility.hpp`: Line 174: `CV_EXPORTS ErrorCallback redirectError( ErrorCallback errCallback, void* userdata=0, void** prevUserdata=0);`

But the undefined reference wants some int an char pointers as parameters, but I don't find such a function in any source file.

When deactivating BUILD_EXAMPLES/PERF_TESTS/TESTS (as suggested somewhere else) this does not fix the problem, but gives the same problem later on:

```
[ 95%] Linking CXX shared library ..\..\bin\libopencv_calib3d310.dll
CMakeFiles\opencv_calib3d.dir/objects.a(calibinit.cpp.obj):calibinit.cpp:(.text$_ZN2cv15findCirclesGridERKNS_11_InputArrayENS_5Size_IiEERKNS_12_OutputArrayEiRKNS_3PtrINS_9Feature2DEEE+0x426): undefined reference to `cv::redirectError(int (*)(int, char const*, char const*, char const*, int, void*), void*, void**)'
CMakeFiles\opencv_calib3d.dir/objects.a(calibinit.cpp.obj):calibinit.cpp:(.text$_ZN2cv15findCirclesGridERKNS_11_InputArrayENS_5Size_IiEERKNS_12_OutputArrayEiRKNS_3PtrINS_9Feature2DEEE+0x44d): undefined reference to `cv::redirectError(int (*)(int, char const*, char const*, char const*, int, void*), void*, void**)'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
modules\calib3d\CMakeFiles\opencv_calib3d.dir\build.make:787: recipe for target 'bin/libopencv_calib3d310.dll' failed
mingw32-make[2]: *** [bin/libopencv_calib3d310.dll] Error 1
CMakeFiles\Makefile2:3634: recipe for target 'modules/calib3d/CMakeFiles/opencv_calib3d.dir/all' failed
mingw32-make[1]: *** [modules/calib3d/CMakeFiles/opencv_calib3d.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:159: recipe for target 'all' failed
mingw32-make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I havn't found any bug report or something else regarding this error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got the same problem. I've solved it with replacing `cv::redirectError` with `cvRedirectError` in ts.cpp as it was before [this patch](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/commit/3a4c14e549ce12ac7b0e8f1e48096054b43efe87#diff-328d03eb0df32533ffd4ddfb45ee4c40R463)

Comment: I additionally had to change ``calibinit.cpp`` in the same way (twice), but then it compiled without errors. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

What I did is I altered `redirectError()` implementation signature in core/src/system.cpp to use `ErrorCallback` instead of `CvErrorCallback` for both an argument and the return value type, to match its declaration signature. Not sure why that matters though, as the both typedefs look identical; it helped nevertheless.